# Python Challenge: Level 2 - Big O Notation

Tags: python

I solved question 2 on the [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html) using the solution below:

```
@fn_timer #Decorator to time the function
def decipher():

    page_source2 = "$%^&*(#*(@#*$(#@*$(@#*$" #This is a subset of the  characters the problem asked you to look through for rare characters. 

    usedvalues = ""
    count = 1
    finalanswer = ""

    for i in range(len(page_source2)):

        if (page_source2[i]) not in usedvalues:
            count = 1
            usedvalues += (page_source2[i])

            for j in range(i, len(page_source2) - i):            
                if (page_source2[i]) in (page_source2[j]):
                    count += 1

            if (count == 1 or count ==2):
                finalanswer += page_source2[i]                  

    return finalanswer

decipher()
```

I am aware that this is not the most efficient solution and I have explored other solutions.

Would I be correct in saying that in this solution for every input of a new unique character the runtime will increase O(N^2) and for every input of a new non-unique character that is already in the string the runtime will increase by O(N)?

Comment: Hint: O(n)*O(m) = O(n*m)

Comment: So for a set of unique characters (m) and non-unique characters (n) the "i loop" will see a runtime O(m). The "j loop" will see a runtime O(n+m). Thus a total runtime O(m)*O(n+m) = O(m*(n+m)) = O(m^2 + nm)